# Domain Redirection (Advance .htaccess)

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Question 1:

When My Old Domain is: `example1.com` 
The old domain don't have nay existing subdomain.

& My New Domain is: `example2.com` 
The new domain have an existing subdomain, its- `sub.example2.com`

But, 
I want to get the solution about...
When My visitor will visit `SUB.EXAMPLE1.COM` (The subdomain is not existing.) 
He will redirect to  `SUB.EXAMPLE2.COM` & He will able to show the Home/Index page,
Because, the subdomain `SUB.EXAMPLE2.COM` is existing.

Also,
Wehen My visitor will try to visit `AnyThing.example1.com` 
He will redirect to `AnyThing.example2.com` But, I know he can't see anything,
Because, The `AnyThing.example2.com` is not existing subdomain in my server.

Question 2:

When My Old Domain is: `example1.com` 
The old domain don't have nay existing subdomain.

& My New Domain is: `example2.com` 
The new domain have an existing subdomain, its- `sub.example2.com`

But, 
I want to get the solution about...
When My visitor will visit `SUB.EXAMPLE1.COM/SOMETHING/` (The subdomain is not existing.) 
He will redirect to  `SUB.EXAMPLE2.COM/SOMETHING/` & He will able to show the Home/Index page,
Because, the subdomain `SUB.EXAMPLE2.COM/SOMETHING/` is existing.

Also,
Wehen My visitor will try to visit AnyThing.example1.com/SOMETHING/ 
He will redirect to `AnyThing.example2.com/SOMETHING/` But, I know he can't see anything,
Because, The `AnyThing.example2.com/SOMETHING/` is not existing subdomain in my server.

Thank You

Comment: How user can visit non existing domain? All (sub)domains must exist and point to the same place.

Comment: I am just thinking Have any way to get & process my all subdomain request? Like Catch All Email.

Comment: Make proper DNS record like *.domain and set a virtual host where you can do redirects.

Comment: Ok, Thank you for your help. I understood about this :)